# Shell execute Return 2 and not open file

Tags: vba

I have a routine in which I try to open some files with any extension txt, pdf, doc, xls, ... that I always worked now when I try to open the
Filename = " 8_20190311144227. jpg "
When passed a string variable I don't open if the string insert directly into the open the file opens
in the first case the return = 2 in the second return = 42
This routine that I use:

```
 Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

      Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
           Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                ByVal lpFile As String, _
                ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                ByVal nShowCmd As Long _
              ) As Long

 Public Sub OpenFile(by val FileName As String, stPath As String)
         'ShellExecute 0, "Open", FileName, "", "", 1
         Dim result As Long, hwnd As Long
         hwnd = GetActiveWindow&
        result = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", FileName, "", stPath, SW_MAXIMIZE)
        'FileName= "8_20190311144227.jpg"
End Sub
```

Grazie per l'aiuto

Comment: Are you saying it works fine unless your *Filename* parameter consists of all numbers?

Comment: Thanks I solved
the filename  in the filename parameter  if it wants to complete the path even if  you go with the path parameter